# VBA to delete cells in a column and shift-left based on the cell's value?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I delete cells in column B (and shift-left) if the cell is empty?

Below is what I have but it's giving an "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

```
Sub DeleteCellShiftLeft()
    For i = 1000 To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, B).Value = "") Then
        Cells(i, B).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `B`?  If you mean column B, then it should be `2`, since it's a numeric offset.