# How can I fix the slipped rows in excel by VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file which includes a lot of rows. Every second rows are slipped. How can I fix these slipped rows by VBA?

I have attached a little template:
[image]

And what can I do if the blank cells are there on the right side?

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332889/vba-to-delete-cells-in-a-column-and-shift-left-based-on-the-cells-value).

Comment: Select column A, Home tab, Find drop-down, goto special, Blanks, delete , and select the shift to left option https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1065-excel-select-empty-cells.html#a

Comment: And what can I do if the blanks cells are on the right side (because 'shift to right' option is not exists)?

Comment: @blackcornail - you have enough reputation to edit your question with the other options you are looking for rather than add a comment with a new question ***after*** people have taken the time to post answers to your original question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the VBA version of my comment with shift to left:

```
Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlShiftToLeft
```

There is no shift to right delete, but there are few ways around it depending on the layout. A more general approach can be to move the blank cells selection to the left and use insert shift to right, but I am not sure how to do that without VBA. 
For example, selecting the blank cells in column F and inserting the corresponding cells on the same rows in column A:

```
Intersect(Range("A:A"), Range("F:F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow).Insert xlShiftToRight
```

A more general approach for more random blank areas is to shift each row separately:

```
With ActiveCell.Worksheet.UsedRange  ' or change to a different range
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlShiftToLeft ' to shift all non-blank cells to the left
    For Each area In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Areas
        area.Offset(, .Column - area.Column).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Next
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumes data in columns A to F

```
Sub Main()
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range

    Set rng = Range("B1:B" & Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row)

    For Each cl In rng
        If cl.Offset(0, -1) = vbNullString Then
            Range(Cells(cl.Row, cl.Column), Cells(cl.Row, 6)).Cut Destination:=cl.Offset(0, -1)
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  Sub slipp_fix()

    Set ww = Application.Selection
    Set ww = Application.InputBox("Select first col of table", xTitleId, ww.Address, Type:=8)

    For Each C In ww
    If C.Value = "" Then
    C.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End If

    Next
end sub
```